# How to page break inside and element with css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a template for print letters with HTML and CSS. I am using ASP.Net 2.0 and C# to set position of HTML elements dynamically.
In this fiddle I've put HTML example of what I want. Problem is that I have header and footer which should be printed on every page. When I have a long letter, main content goes behind the header and footer and could not manage pagination of the desire template. I've done a lots of search and read many answers here but still there is no solution.

```css
@page {
  margin-right: 1cm;
  margin-bottom=0cm;
  margin-top=0cm;
  margin-left=0cm;
}

div#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0mm;
  left: 0mm;
  width: 100%;
}

div#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0mm;
  left: 0mm;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0mm;
  left: 0mm;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" onClick="window.print();">Print</a>
</div>
<table width="100%">

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="header">
        <span id="ILettarh13_MLbl" style="font-weight:bold;position:absolute; top : 15mm; left : 150mm;">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <span id="ILettarh16_Lbl" style="font-weight:bold;position:absolute; top : 25mm; left : 150mm;">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <span id="ILettarh19_Lbl" style="font-weight:bold;position:absolute; top : 35mm; left : 150mm;">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <span id="ILettarh11_Lbl" style="position:absolute; top : 22mm; left : 55mm;">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span id="ILettarh22_Lbl" style="position:absolute; top : 55mm; left : 15mm; page-break-after:always;">
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><br>
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><br>
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><br>
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><br>
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><br>
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><br>
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><br>
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><br>
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><br>
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><br>
 </span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="footer">
        <img id="ILettarh35_Img" src="http://placehold.it/720x120" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ax80mr/3/)

Comment: The reason you are struggling with the JSFiddle link is because your code must be included within your question. You can't post a link to JSFiddle without code.

Comment: @Turnip I've tried many times. but I didn't get it.

Comment: What is it really you want to achieve? Have pages with Prev 1,2,3.. Next buttons or?

Comment: @FortyTwo Ideal situation is that I have buttons in `@media` screen. But for now I just want a clean and simple print of all pages with header and footer.